# Joining results of two independent query

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two working queries:

1st returns the product list:

```
$sql = "
   SELECT a.stockID, a.stockCatID, a.stockName, a.stockCode, a.stockCatCode,
   CONCAT_WS(' » ', d.stockCatName, c.stockCatName, b.stockCatName) AS stockPath,
   a.stockName AS stockTitle, a.stockID AS uniStock
   FROM stockcards a
   LEFT OUTER JOIN stockcategories b
     ON a.stockCatID = b.stockCatID
   LEFT OUTER JOIN stockcategories c
     ON b.stockParentCat = c.stockCatID
   LEFT  OUTER JOIN stockcategories d
     ON c.stockParentCat = d.stockCatID ";
```

2nd is basically returns the difference of total received and total sent whic is remaining quantity:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (COALESCE(o.totalReceived, 0) + COALESCE(p.totalSent, 0)) as RemainingStock
 FROM deliverydetails k 
 INNER JOIN stockcards l ON k.stockID= l.stockID
 LEFT JOIN
     (
         SELECT m.stockID, SUM(m.dQuantity) totalReceived
         FROM deliverydetails m
         WHERE m.dQuantity > 0
         GROUP BY m.stockID
     )
     o ON k.stockID = o.stockID
 LEFT JOIN
     (
         SELECT n.stockID, SUM(n.dQuantity) totalSent
         FROM deliverydetails n
         WHERE n.dQuantity < 0
         GROUP BY n.stockID
     )
     p ON k.stockID = p.stockID
```

I need to add a new column to first query to display remanining quantity. But couldn't succeed to join this two. Thanks for any tip.

Answer (score 0):

As it seems that your 2nd query just sums positive and negative dQuantities for each stockID, and then adds them together, I think this small change to your 1st query is
all that is needed:

```
SELECT a.stockID, a.stockCatID, a.stockName, a.stockCode, a.stockCatCode,
   CONCAT_WS(' » ', d.stockCatName, c.stockCatName, b.stockCatName) AS stockPath,
   a.stockName AS stockTitle, a.stockID AS uniStock,
   dd.RemainingStock AS RemainingStock 
   FROM stockcards a
   LEFT OUTER JOIN stockcategories b
     ON a.stockCatID = b.stockCatID
   LEFT OUTER JOIN stockcategories c
     ON b.stockParentCat = c.stockCatID
   LEFT  OUTER JOIN stockcategories d
     ON c.stockParentCat = d.stockCatID
   LEFT OUTER JOIN 
     (SELECT stockID, SUM(dQuantity) AS RemainingStock
     FROM deliverydetails
     GROUP BY stockID) AS dd
   ON dd.stockID = a.stockID
```